# Fundamental Frequency values for Rexnord ZA-2115 bearing

Tags: bearings, frequency-response, data, specifications

I am having difficulty coming to terms with the [Rexnord ZA-2115 bearing](https://www.rexnord.com/products/za2115) technical specifications. This bearing is used in the [*NASA Bearing Dataset*](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vinayak123tyagi/bearing-dataset) where the Rexnord bearings are tested at 2000 RPM under a 6000 pound load. My questions in particular are:

(A) The *Vibration Frequency Fundamental Train*, *Inner Ring Defect*, *Outer Ring Defect*, and *Roller Spin* values are specified as 0.0072, 0.1617, 0.1217, 0.0559 cps, respectively. I might assume these are somehow [related to](https://books.google.com/books?id=_2RXEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA358) *Fundamental Train Frequency* (FTF), *Ballpass frequency outer race* (BPFO), *Ballpass frequency inner race* (BPFI), and *Ball spin frequency* (BSF).
$\begin{array}{lcl|}
FTF &=&\frac{R}{2}\left(1-\frac{d}{D}\cos\phi\right)\\
BPFO&=&\frac{nR}{2}\left(1-\frac{d}{D}\cos\phi\right)\\
BPFI&=&\frac{nR}{2}\left(1+\frac{d}{D}\cos\phi\right)\\
BSF &=&\frac{DR}{2d}\left[1-\left(\frac{d}{D}\cos\phi\right)^2\right]
\end{array}$
where $n$ is the number of balls, $R$ is rotational speed, and $\phi$ is the contact angle.

But how do I get (and/or should I be able to get) from the Rexnord values to the (FTF, BPFO, BPFI, BSF) 4-tuple? Do I need to multiply Rexnord values by shaft rotational frequency? For example, is 0.0072 x RPM/60 equal to FTF in Hertz?

(B) How can I determine the number of rolling elements in ZA-2115? Since BPFO and FTF only differ by a factor $n$, then I might think that $n$ should equal BPFO / FTF (regardless of RPM). However, when I calculate 0.1217 / 0.0072, I get approximately  16.9 ... shouldn't I get an integer? Or are the values derived empirically using actual test data and a PSD?
[image]

Some PSD-Welch calculations suggests peaks at the following locations for $x$ axis
$\begin{array}{cc}
  492.95775 \;Hz& 2.1302751\\
  985.91549 \;Hz& 3.6660246\\
 4201.87793 \;Hz& 1.4599044\\
 5164.31925 \;Hz& 1.5721200\\
 7018.77934 \;Hz& 1.3078587\\
 9061.03286 \;Hz& 1.6893742
\end{array}$
and $y$ axis
$\begin{array}{cc}
  492.957746  \;Hz&  1.497\\
  985.915493  \;Hz&  1.596\\
  5164.319249 \;Hz&  1.024\\
  7136.150235 \;Hz&  0.979\\
  8990.610329 \;Hz&  2.115
\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

the BPFO is 236.4Hz. You can reference some of the publications that used this dataset like: DOI: 10.1016/j.jsv.2005.03.007

Page 19 gives the design parameters to calculate the fault frequencies of the Rexnord ZA-2115 used in the test.
” Four Rexnord ZA-2115 double row bearings were installed on one shaft as shown in Fig. 16. The bearings have 16 rollers in each row, a pitch diameter of 2.815 in., roller diameter of 0.331 in., and a tapered contact angle of 15.171. “

You can use this information and a simple bearing fault frequency calculator to determine the BPFO, FTF, BPFI and BSF at different running speeds. [![Fault frequencies of ZA-2115][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lIt8.jpg

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have anything else you'll like to discuss concerning this dataset.